# Number of characters in edits

Tags: discussion, editing

Sometimes in edits, you can give the clarification for your changes as " added xx characters to body."

Where is the character count visible on screen? I can not find it from the mobile website.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the "*added <number of symbols> characters in body*" is the standard placeholder for the edit description and is generated automatically if the editor leaves the `Edit Summary` field empty. I normally wouldn't count this as "*clarification for your changes*" as it doesn't really clarifies anything. If you want to see the delta in your edit prior to publishing, use an advanced third-party text editor on your device.

Comment: Please provide an edit summary, the automatically generated messages are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 4):

Those edit summaries are [automatically generated by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91769/295232); others are 'edited tags' and 'edited title'. You do not see a character count on the screen, neither on mobile nor on the desktop version of the site, since it's not important, except for one thing: when you *suggest* an edit to another user's post, it must be 6 characters at minimum. (If you fail to do so, an error will be shown upon submitting the edit.) Also, you must provide a custom edit summary yourself, so that reviewers will know *why* you edited the post. Common reasons include "grammar corrections" and "formatting".

If you edit your own post, or have [2,000 or more reputation](/help/privileges/edit), you do not need to provide an edit summary, but if the changes are non-obvious it's nice if you do provide one.